# Why define a schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB and mongoose, I read that mongodb is schema-less, but I also read that one can and encouraged to define a schema.
Why would I need to define a schema if the db doesn't require one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because more often than not, the documents in your database represent instances of re-usable object containers (prototypes / classes). These typically look at least largely similar.

While there is a plethora of programming paradigms concerned with object structure / type systems (polymorphism, [protoypical / multiple] inheritance, duck typing, etc.) the common denominator is that it makes sense to somehow arrange certain data fields together.

Since MongoDB doesn't enforce a strict schema, it is compatible with almost all of these paradigms. When using MongoDB to store instances of re-usable container types, it simply makes sense to define such a schema, be it because it helps the wrapper offer convenience methods, validation helpers or inject sensible defaults.

You could, however, also use MongoDB as a large hashtable for JSON documents - in that case, a schema doesn't make sense.